# How to free resources in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, memory, base64

I have a web page which continuously fetches base64 images from server and set it as source to image now i can see in dev tab that the resources memory is increasing

```
58.1 MB / 58.1 MB resources
Finish: 33.41 s
DOMContentLoaded: 575 ms
```

How can i free these resources as i do not use these image at all later.

Here is the code:

```
            fetch('/post', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                //Some Body Here
            })
        }).then((res) => {
            if(res.status == 200){
                var resText = res.text().then((responseText) => {
                    document.getElementById("image").src = "data:image/png;base64," + (JSON.parse(responseText).base64);
                });
            }
        });
```

How can i free this data to optimize the performance.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you transform the response to text, then parse it again from text to JSON, you might as well get it directly as JSON with `res.json()`

Comment: Actually i am using a lot of custom backend (both NodeJS as well as some custom Java Backend so i am trying to be simple)

Comment: @JeremyThille moreover i guess thats not the problem as the string should get garbage collected automatically